# PHP cria números nas casas decimais

Tags: php, arredondamento

estou quebrando a cabeça aqui. Eu passo para uma variável o valor de 130.67. Depois subtraio dela um valor qualquer e depois subraio o restante para deixar a variável com valor 0 (exato). Depois eu testo se o valor é igual a 0. Mas dá erro, e quando eu mando exibir o máximo de casas possíveis (53) vejo que quando eu passo o valor inicial, ao invés de ter 130.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 eu tenho 130,66999999999998749444785062223672866821289062500000000. Ou seja, o PHP passa automaticamente valores para as terceiras casas decimais em diante. Já tentei usar o round($var, 2), mas não dá certo. Vi que essa "criação de valores" difere para outros números.

```
<?php
$valor1 = 130.67;
$valor2 = $valor1 - 10;
$valor3 = $valor2 - 120.67;
if ($valor3 == 0) {
    print "Valor zerado";
} else {
    print "Erro, há saldo";
}
?>
```

Comment: Existem diversas questões e respostas aqui no SOpt falando sobre a imprecisão intrínseca dos números de ponto flutuante. Se deseja precisão então não utilize os tipos de dados float/double.

Comment: Só apareceu: Erro, há saldo

Comment: Recomendo usar double